# Effect of different GPU frequency ranges in Intel Core M

Tags: gpu

I just noticed that with the Broadwell line of Intel CPUs, Wikipedia for the first time lists a GPU frequency, and that range is different for each chip despite the GPU model being the same.

```
Model       sSpec      Cores Frequency Turbo    GPU              GPU      
number      number                              model            frequency
Core M-5Y10 SR217 (E0) 2     800 MHz   2 GHz    HD Graphics 5300 100–800 MHz
Core M-5Y31 SR23G (F0) 2     900 MHz   2.4 GHz  HD Graphics 5300 300–850 MHz    
Core M-5Y70 SR216 (E0) 2     1.1 GHz   2.6 GHz  HD Graphics 5300 100–850 MHz    
Core M-5Y71 SR23Q (F0) 2     1.2 GHz   2.9 GHz  HD Graphics 5300 300–900 MHz
```

(Selectively copied from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core#Core_M)

The top end of the GPU frequency range seems to increase as the frequency of the CPU increases, which makes sense, but I have a few questions:

1) Why is the top end of the range only 850MHz for a 900MHz CPU? The M-5Y51 GPU does get to 900MHz, so 850MHz isn't the GPUs' limit.

2) Why does the bottom end of the range jump from 100 to 300MHz for some chips?

3) What effect do these differences have on power consumption/battery life?  Does a GPU with a higher minimum GPU consume more power in idle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the top end of the range only 850MHz for a 900MHz CPU?

Intel determine this was the maximum frequency their design could handle.

> Why does the bottom end of the range jump from 100 to 300MHz for some
>   chips?

Intentional product separation.  It also isn't a minimum is the base frequency the higher number is the boost frequency.

"*Graphics max dynamic frequency refers to the maximum opportunistic graphics render clock frequency (in MHz) that can be supported using Intel® HD Graphics with Dynamic Frequency feature*"

> What effect do these differences have on power consumption/battery
>   life?

Battery life estimates take the GPU into consideration.  The estimates also depend on how large of a battery is placed in the device.  Of course Intel provides the amount of power the CPU uses which allows for anyone to estimate how many hours it will run on a particular batter.

> Does a GPU with a higher minimum GPU consume more power in idle?

Intel's power consumption takes the GPU design into consideration.